# How do I create a table with hierarchy in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am trying to create a table in Big Query which has hierarchical data as below.

**tier_1, tier_2, tier_3** fields are all of **string** datatype where as **cities** field is **array of strings**.

[image]

Could someone please help me in creating the table. Also, please help in retrieving the data as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated answer below.

Create Table Statement

```
CREATE TABLE test.hier ( 
  Tier1 STRING,
  Tier2 ARRAY<STRUCT <
        Tier2_name String, 
        Tier3 ARRAY<STRUCT < 
              Tier3_name String, 
              Cities ARRAY<Struct< 
                  City_name ARRAY<STRING>>>>>>>

)
```

Insert Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO test.hier ( Tier1,Tier2)

VALUES ('Asia', [STRUCT('India' as Tier2_name,[ 
                        STRUCT('Tamilnadu' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Chennai', 'Vellore', 'Coimbatore'] as City_name)]), 
                        STRUCT('Kerala' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Palakad', 'Kannur', 'Cochin'] as City_name)])
                        ]
                        ), STRUCT('Srilanka' as Tier2_name,[ 
                        STRUCT('West' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Colombo', 'Kotte'] as City_name)]), 
                        STRUCT('Central' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Katana', 'Matale'] as City_name)])
                        ]
                        )     ]),
                        
        ('North America', [STRUCT('USA' as Tier2_name,[ 
                        STRUCT('Washington' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Seattle', 'Olymbia'] as City_name)]), 
                        STRUCT('Arizona' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Tempe', 'Phoneix'] as City_name)])
                        ]
                        ), STRUCT('Canada' as Tier2_name,[ 
                        STRUCT('Onatrio' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Toronto', 'Ottawa'] as City_name)]), 
                        STRUCT('Alberta' as Tier3_name, [STRUCT(['Edmonton', 'Calgary'] as City_name)])
                        ]
                        )     ])
```

Bigquery Output

[image: Request Output Format]

Comment: Hey @Vijay, Thanks for your answer. But I want it like a hierarchy, nested kind of schema.

Comment: Hi @Vijay, Thanks for your answer. Here, the field names are a bit confusing and lengthy. Could you please share a sample INSERT for the below schema? 

CREATE TABLE test.hier ( 
  Tier1 ARRAY<STRUCT <
          Tier2 ARRAY<STRUCT < 
              Tier3 ARRAY<STRUCT < 
                    cities ARRAY<STRING>>>>>>>

)

Comment: The given schema does not define columns of Tier 1, Tier 2, Tier 3 . Please read about Array and struct data types to understand more about how to define array and struct data types.   Check the below link to understand more.  https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-work-with-array-and-structs-in-bigquery-9c0a2ea584a6